# Unable to add custom routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am using the mailboxer gem in my rails app to handle private messages between users. I have a separate page to view your inbox and a separate page to view your trash folder. The URL localhost/conversations succesfully loaded the inbox. I want to have a link that can load a separate page for trash, such as localhost/conversations/trashbin. However, I can't get Rails to recognize any routes I create for such a page.

In addition, going directly to that URL displays and error:

`Couldn't find Conversation with id=trashbin`

I understand why the error is occurring but I don't know how to fix it. The issue is with my routes file:

```
resources :conversations do
    member do
      post :reply
      post :trash
      post :untrash
      get 'trashbin', :action => 'trashbin'
    end
  end
```

Using `resources` is causing the app to look for a specific conversation. This is useful throughout the rest of the application  except for this one case. I simply want to collect all of the messages that were marked as trash. How can I edit this routes file to accomplish this?

Here are the links I have on the index conversations page:

```
<a href="<%= conversations_path %>"> <%= @conversations.count %> Inbox </a> | <a href="<% trashbin_conversations_path %>"> <%= @trash.count %> Trash </a>
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks to the answers below I have updated the routes to:

```
resources :conversations do
  member do
    post :reply
    post :trash
    post :untrash
  end
  collection do
    get :trashbin
  end
end
```

However, the URL conversations/trashbin now displays an Unknown action error:
`The action 'trashbin' could not be found for ConversationsController`

My ConversationsController clearly has the action defined. Why is this error appearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a member route - use a collection route instead:

```
resources :conversations do
  member do
    post :reply
    post :trash
    post :untrash
  end
  collection do
    get :trashbin
  end
end
```

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) for more info on this.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a step in the right direction. Going directly to /conversations/trashbin leaves me with the Unknown action although I clearly have `def trashbin` in my conversations controller. Any ideas as to why it can't find the action in my controller?

Comment: @james - have you reloaded your Rails server env?

Comment: Yes, I just restarted the local development environment with no luck :/

Comment: Could it be the name of the html.erb file? What should it be called?

Comment: Your view should be called `trashbin.html.erb`, unless you are specifically rendering some other content...

Comment: Yup, I think that was the problem with regards to unknown action. I had renamed it to include an underscore when I tried changing as many things as I could to find out what the issue was. Forgot to change it back. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I noticed that now the trashbin page returns nil for all of the instance variables (it's identical to the index action in the controller). Posted a question for it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892406/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-identical-controller-action-works-fine?noredirect=1#comment31356805_20892406 . Any ideas as to why the collection route doesn't allow the same access to the data as the resources route?

Answer (score 2):

Put the route in a collection scope

```
  resources :conversations do
    member do
      post :reply
      post :trash
      post :untrash
    end
    collection do
      get :trashbin
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is right but the URL conversations/trashbin displays an Unknown action error, even though the trashbin action is clearly defined in the controller. Do you know what the cause could be ?

Comment: Try running rake routes in the console and see if you can find the route there