# undefined method for nil:NilClass, identical controller action works fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ConversationsController with two identical actions:

```
 def index
    @conversations ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox.all
    @trash ||= current_user.mailbox.trash.all
  end  
  def trashbin
    @conversations ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox.all
    @trash ||= current_user.mailbox.trash.all
  end
```

The only difference is the information that is displayed in the views. The index page displays the data just fine. However, I get the following error for every instance variable that appears in the trashbin view:

`undefined method 'count' for nil:NilClass`

View:

`<%= @conversations.count %>`

Count just so happens to be the first method used in the view page. The views between the two actions are almost identical except for some plain text. I'm stumped as to why I'm getting an error on one action. I'm using `<%= @conversations.count %>` on the index page and it works fine.

The only possibility is an error with the routes file. I had some trouble getting the custom trashbin route to work so I'm thinking the issue is with the routes file:

```
resources :conversations do
  member do
    post :reply
    post :trash
    post :untrash
  end
  collection do
    get :trashbin, :action => 'trashbin'
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

EDIT: Updated routes code (all of it has been posted).

Also, here is the error generated in the terminal:

`Started GET "/conversations/trashbin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-02 17:38:34 -0500
Processing by ConversationsController#trashbin as HTML
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered conversations/trashbin.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)`

Comment: You're showing a little code, but not the code that actually fails.

Comment: Updated the question, sorry about that. The first variable that fails is `<%= @conversations.count %>`. It works fine in the index page, but fails on the trashbin page. Why would that instance variable return nil when it clearly returns values in the other controller action? I'm so stumped!

Comment: The only logical conclusion I can draw, based upon what you show so far, is that when the `trashbin` view is exercised, the value returned from `current_user.mailbox.inbox.all` is `nil` for some reason.

Comment: Could the "collection" route have anything to do with it? Trashbin seems to be outside the "resources" route for conversations so I'm thinking that it doesn't have the same access to the data

Comment: Perhaps, that's the second possibility: the `trashbin` method in the controller may not be executed.

Comment: what is the url you are using? /conversations/trashbin?

Comment: Could you post your `routes.rb` file? Also, if you put debugging output into your methods in ConversationsController, which one actually fires? (You could also post what the log file says about which action is being executed.)

Comment: Updated question with full routes and error log. I think the SELECT statement from the log is really fishy. Why is it only trying to Select from users where id=1?

Comment: Do you have any `before_filter`s?

Comment: only before_filter I'm using is `before_filter :authenticate_user!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a rookie mistake on my part. The "identical" action in the controller wasn't exactly identical. The controller action that wasn't working properly was listed under Private, which explains why the instance variable wasn't accessible to the view -_-.

Sorry for wasting your time everyone!